# .ICS file are not showing in the folder

Tags: android, icalendar, android-calendar

I have written a small code for creating file in .ics format in external storage with directory.
Now the problem is with .ics file is not showing in the directory. when I change it to .txt format it is showing. what's the wrong with this code?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid1@example.com
DTSTAMP:19970714T170000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe:MAILTO:john.doe@example.com
DTSTART:19970714T170000Z
DTEND:19970715T035959Z
SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR    

String begin = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR";

public void generateNoteOnSD(Context context) {
    try {
        String filename = "TEST.ics";
        FileOutputStream bw = openFileOutput(filename, MODE_PRIVATE);
        byte b[] = begin.getBytes();
        bw.write(b);
        bw.close();
        Log.d("successful", "written complete");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The flaw is in your logic.

If the directory `ICS` already exists, you are trying to write to a file `TEST.ics` in that directory. This should work. And if it doesn’t, you should get an `IOException` and see its stack trace.

The problem is if the directory doesn’t already exist. In this case your code creates the directory and then does nothing more. It also doesn’t detect whether the creation of the directory has succeeded. So the file isn’t created.

Instead you need two changes:

- `directoryDIR.mkdir()` returns a `boolean` to indicate whether the creation of the directory was successful. You need to check this return value and report to the user if you get `false`.
- The code for writing the file should not go into the `else` part. Instead there shouldn’t be an `else` part, and the code should just come after the `if` statement, that is, after the closing `}` brace of it.

Comment: I understand what you said, now the problem is i need to save this file in ics format and I need to share that file which is shared internally. I just update my code can you please verify it again?

Comment: I update code with my example format, I cleary don't know how to achive this but still, I keep trying like this all stupid ideas i got. can u please help me with this?

Comment: @user10743129 I can’t see anything wrong with your code now, but I don’t know where the file will be written to. I don’t know Android and can’t help you with the sharing,sorry.

Comment: Ole V.V. Now the file is currently storing in my app package under files folder. ok, thanks for your help.